relative import for class fails
not sure why I always struggle with relative imports...
usually I have this structure
- project
  - package1
      some.py
  - package2
  - tests
     tests_package1.py

where tests_package1.py starts with
from ..packe1.some import some

however I get "attempted relative import with no known parent package" and depening on where I have which init.py other errors.
here I found many suggestions but all fail in one or the other way
how to correctly import a class some in some.py from the tets_package1.py ?
Changed the question to make clear I want to run a test of some class in some.py called from tests in test_package1.py.

Is tests a package?

In my experience with relative imports, any files inside the package need to be called from the outside - eg. have a run_tests.py alongside project and inside that use from project.tests import test_package1.

no tests is not a package.

Then you can't use relative import.

You can create run_tests.py in project directory with something like this
from package1.some import some
from tests.tests_package1 import tests

and pass some into tests as argument
tests(some)


only if I am at a parent path

this worked for me if tests are in a folder structure as shown above
by extending the system path I was able to import as from a parent folder. The only thing sad about that is that no IDE will help you with that
# extend system path
file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
code_dir = os.path.dirname(file_dir)
sys.path.append(code_dir)

not nice but worked for me....
